# Maintaining alignment of navigation items of different widths on smaller screens

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries

I am trying to align my navigation menu on my wordpress website. The only issue I have is that when the browser is scaled down to mobile `width`... the last item in the navigation is not aligned with other items in the navigation because the item before it is only 3 letters long.

Preview:

[image]

My code:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<nav id="nav">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav') ); ?>
</nav>
```

I am using media queries currently:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 388px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    .nav li:last-child a {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}
```

But when I resize the browser... it goes to that point where the aligning is messed up at `width 388px` while on my `iphone 6` it goes to that point at `width 375px`. Is there a better way to align my menu or should I stick to media queries here?

**UPDATE**

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6x2aha6/)**

Please change the width to 438px on the JSFiddle output panel to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make all nav items the same width, so they all consume equal space on the page?

Try this:

```
#nav li {
  /* padding: 0 16px;  <-- remove; use text-align instead */
  font: 400 18px/13px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black; /* for illustration only */
}
```

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/w6x2aha6/2/)